# How to make the dd command be verbose?

Tags: command-line

I want to make a USB bootable by cloning an image. I did some research and I haven't found a satisfactory way of making dd provide some feedback back to the console of how the progress is going.

Is there a way, built into the command to do this, aside from polling the PID via the ps command?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you read `man dd`, it refers you to `info coreutils 'dd invocation'` which says, in part,

Sending an `INFO` signal to a running `dd` process makes it print
I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.  In the
example below, `dd` is run in the background to copy 10 million blocks.
The `kill` command makes it output intermediate I/O statistics, and
when `dd` completes normally or is killed by the `SIGINT` signal, it
outputs the final statistics.

```
 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10MB & pid=$!
 $ kill -s INFO $pid; wait $pid
 3385223+0 records in
 3385223+0 records out
 1733234176 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 6.42173 seconds, 270 MB/s
 10000000+0 records in
 10000000+0 records out
 5120000000 bytes (5.1 GB) copied, 18.913 seconds, 271 MB/s
```

On systems lacking the `INFO` signal `dd` responds to the `USR1`
signal instead, unless the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is
set.

You can also try the `status=progress` option, which will display the info in real time:

```
[~]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=10MB status=progress
4708234752 bytes (4.7 GB, 4.4 GiB) copied, 4 s, 1.2 GB/s
10000000+0 records in
10000000+0 records out
5120000000 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 4.3516 s, 1.2 GB/s
[~]$
```

Comment: nice solution. Please note that count is only for demonstration purposes and for me MB was not working. It expects a number. Also I do not have a progress option for status in my dd. A one-liner for observing dd would be 'while kill -0 $pid; do kill -s INFO $pid;done'

Comment: status=progress is probably what 99.99% of everyone is looking for, but reading about INFO and USR1 signals is nice, reminds me how little I know about everything

Answer (score 28):

There are several solutions available via google search.

From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/

```
(pv -n /dev/sda | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=128M conv=notrunc,noerror) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Running dd command (cloning), please wait..." 10 70 0
```

[image]

You may have to install dialog and pv

```
sudo apt-get install pv dialog
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but any comments on what the different values do? 10 70 0? etc?